# Summing up Certain Sequences of a Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have several data frames of daily rates of different regions by age-groups:

```
Date         0-14 Rate     15-29 Rate  30-44 Rate   45-64 Rate 65-79 Rate  80+ Rate   
2020-23-12     0              33.54      45.68       88.88        96.13      41.28 
2020-24-12     0              25.14      35.28       66.14        90.28      38.41
```

It begins on Wednesday (2020-23-12) and I have data from then on up to date.

I want to obtain weekly row sums of rates from each Wednesday to Tuesday.

There should be a wise way of combinations with aggregate, seq and rowsum functions to do this using a few lines. Otherwise, I'll use too long ways to do this.

Comment: What is your desired output format?

Answer (score 1):

I created some minimal data, three weeks with some arbitrary column and numerics (no missings). You can use `tidyverse` language to sum over columns, create groups per week and sum over rowsums by week:

```
# Minimal Data 
MWE <- data.frame(date = c(outer(as.Date("12/23/20", "%m/%d/%y"), 0:20, `+`)),
                  column1 = runif(21,0,1),
                  column2 = runif(21,0,1))

library(tidyverse)

MWE %>%
  # Calculate Row Sum Everywhere
  mutate(sum = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)))) %>%
  # Create Week Groups
  group_by(week = ceiling(row_number()/7)) %>%
  # Sum Over All RowSums per Group 
  summarise(rowSums_by_week = sum(sum))


# Groups:   week [3]
   date       column1 column2   sum  week
   <date>       <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2020-12-23   0.449  0.759  1.21      1
 2 2020-12-24   0.423  0.0956 0.519     1
 3 2020-12-25   0.974  0.592  1.57      1
 4 2020-12-26   0.798  0.250  1.05      1
 5 2020-12-27   0.870  0.487  1.36      1
 6 2020-12-28   0.952  0.345  1.30      1
 7 2020-12-29   0.349  0.817  1.17      1
 8 2020-12-30   0.227  0.727  0.954     2
 9 2020-12-31   0.292  0.209  0.501     2
10 2021-01-01   0.678  0.276  0.954     2
# ... with 11 more rows

# A tibble: 3 x 2
   week rowSums_by_week
  <dbl>           <dbl>
1     1            8.16
2     2            6.02
3     3            6.82
```